# Fetching Facebook Status updates using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, facebook-oauth, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-node-sdk

I want to Fetch  Every Facebook Status update i make from my Fb Account  using NodeJS and print it in my console ...Can this process be event driven,Is there a way wherein a event is generated and the NodeJs server is notified when a new facebook status update is made without polling for it  ???

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a webhook is what you are looking for. I do not know whether or not Facebook offers webhooks. If they do, that should be your solution.